# TextAngular not assigning text-alignment

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using TextAngular for a website I am building and so far it is working great except for two things.

1. `text-align: center` Does not work.
2. `text-align: right` Doest not work.

Now, I have found several similar issues with this but none quite match mine. I found this https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/46 but it is for the buttons not even showing up. My buttons show up, they just don't work the way they are supposed to. I also found this https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/82 and it is closer to what is going on, but still not quite it.

Let me go into detail about what is going on.

I have two textAngular input boxes, they both use the same toolbar, this toolbar shows all options available. When I type in one of the input fields it will copy over to the second input field (up to 150 chars, it's a summary), all the styling buttons work such as the h1-p buttons, the bold works, the underline works, the quotes even work. When I use the text-align buttons it *appears* to work, in the input field it will align to the right or center like it should.  However, upon uploading to the server it does not keep the styling, at first I thought it was stripping out the styling like one of the above links mention, however, the styling doesn't even get *that* far.

One of the options in the toolbar is to see the bare html, so if will make all the p tags and what not appear. When pressing this button it shows everything except text-alignment. This is further confirmed by my second input field not aligning with my 1st field, so if I use the text-align right button it will *appear* to work in the first input box but won't do diddly in the second box.

Here is the form that I wrote:

```
<form name="form-post" ng-submit="save()">
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Title" class="margin-bottom" name="title" ng-model="post.title">
  </div>
  <p>Cover Image</p>
  <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" file-upload file=photo>
  <p>Maximum file size is 1MB.</p>

  <text-angular-toolbar name="toolbar"></text-angular-toolbar>
  <text-angular placeholder="Blog content" name="body" ng-model="post.body" ta-target-toolbars='toolbar' mdp-post></text-angular>
  <text-angular placeholder="Blog Summary" ta-target-toolbars='toolbar' class="margin-bottom margin-top" name="truncBody" ng-model="post.truncBody" mdp-post style="min-height: 30px"></text-angular> 
  </br>
  <button type="submit" class="button-pink">Post</button>
  <button class="button-pink" ui-sref="base.blog">Cancel</button> 
</form>
```

And my controller for it

```
app.controller('postBlogCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Messages', 'blogFactory',
function($scope, $location, Messages, blogFactory) {

  $scope.post = {};
  $scope.post.body = "";

  $scope.date = new Date();

  $scope.save = function() {
    var post = new FormData();
    post.append("title", $scope.post.title);
    post.append("photo", $scope.photo);
    post.append("body", $scope.post.body);
    post.append("truncBody", $scope.post.truncBody);

    var thingsLeft= [];
    function pushIf(array) {
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 2)
      if (arguments[i]) array.push(arguments[i + 1]);
    }

    pushIf(thingsLeft,
      !$scope.post.title, " Title",
      !$scope.photo, " Cover Image",
      !$scope.post.body, " Body",
      !$scope.post.truncBody, " Summary"
    );

    if(thingsLeft.length > 0){
      Messages.error("Please fill out all fields. Fields left:" + thingsLeft);
      return;
    }else{
      blogFactory.postBlog()
      .post(post, {}, {'Content-Type': undefined}).then(function(response) {
        $location.path('/');
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I'm pretty sure that's all the logic that's needed, if you need more code, please tell me. 
But yeah, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is the same issue as one of the links in the question, it is stripping out the style because I am not using textAngular-sanitize.js, here is an almost exact duplicate of my question that has been answered by the creator of text-angular. https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/210